# Is possible to fire __doPostBack twice?

Tags: asp.net, postback

I'm maintaining an ASP .Net Application that seems somehow duplicate a records e.g. using a page add-user. I was unable to reproduce but I found some code that do something crazy like, on submit:

```
if(crazy-code()){
    __doPostBack() // 2nd
}
```

and crazy-code also do something like

```
function crazy-code()
{
    ...
    __doPostBack() // 1st
    ...
    return true;
}
```

To find out this piece of code is causing the problem, I have been trying to fire both `__doPostBack` but I was unable to do it. 
In theory, what should always happens is when it fire the (1st) `__doPostBack`, it should send the request and stop/ignore any client code afterward. 
if `__doPostBack` is fired twice, what will be the reasons? the browsers? the speed? ???

Answer (score 0):

The **__doPostBack()** call will submit the form and it should not call the second one.

I might be wrong, but I think you can reproduce your issue if you hit "Submit" on your web page and after the page reloads hit "F5". Depending on the browser, it will ask something like "resend the from data?". Select "Yes" and check whether your records have been duplicated.

In any case, i think you need to add the checks for duplicated values when you insert the data on the server side.

Comment: I reproduce by reload the page/frame, but it isn't the case. The add-user page is an iframe, so, for instance in Firefox, during the confirmation alert, we have to right click on the frame > This Frame > Reload Frame, and then FF confirmation. And it's not what is creating this duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a testing code. in FF and chrome seems to work fine (1 submit) but the IE9 (and compatibility version) seems to hit 1, 2 or 3 times.
NOTE: the submit() cause the postback.
CASE 1. delay in Javascript
Page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>testing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitForm() {
            document.forms[0].submit();
            alert("delay");
            document.forms[0].submit();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="220px"></asp:TextBox>
        <button onclick="submitForm(this)">CLICK</button>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(IsPostBack)
    {
        incrementVal();
    }
}

private void incrementVal()
{
    var val = (int)(Session["val_" + TextBox1.Text] ?? 0);
    val++;
    Label1.Text += TextBox1.Text + ": " + val.ToString("00") + " - " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "<br/>";
    Session["val_" + TextBox1.Text] = val;
}
```

[image]

CASE 2: Slow Response

remove JS Alert:

```
function submitForm() {
    document.forms[0].submit();
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

add delay in the server side:

```
if(IsPostBack)
{
    incrementVal();
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```